# When does the beat frequency remain unchaged?

Tags: waves

When two prongs are sounded together with the other one being loaded, shouldn't the beat frequency increase and the frequency of prong B will decrease. 
How do we determine the frequency of B in a case where beat frequency remain unchanged on loading?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that before loading the frequency of the fork which will be loaded was higher than the other fork by a certain amount.
Loading then reduces the frequency of the fork below the frequency of the other fork so that the difference in the frequencies of the forks is the same as before.